# igraph select function for generic attributes

Tags: python, igraph

I am learning `igraph`, by following [this tutorial](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/home/tamas/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Here is a *syntax* from the tutorial that I was not familiar before:

```
# g is a Graph object
# g.vs are vertices of g
>>> g.vs.select(age_lt=30)
# this returns vertices which has "age" attribute less than 30
```

I need something more *generic*.

More specifically, I want to get the vertices whose attribute `atr` is smaller than `c`. Say, `atr` is `string` and `c` is `int`.

I tried:

```
>>> atr = 'age'
>>> c = 30
>>> g.vs.select(atr + '_lt'= c)
```

However, I get a `SyntaxError`:

> SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

I don't want to do it manually, like:

```
>>> [v for v in g.vs if v[atr] < c]
```

because my graph is *big*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dict and str.format:

```
atr = 'age'
c = 30

g.vs(**{'{}_lt'.format(atr): c}
```

If you were worried about memory you could also use a gen exp:

```
(v for v in g.vs if v[atr] < c)
```

Both return the same output:

```
In [2]: g = Graph([(0,1), (0,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,2), (2,5), (5,0), (6,3), (5,6)])

In [3]: g.vs["name"] = ["Alice", "Bob", "Claire", "Dennis", "Esther", "Frank", "George"]   
In [4]: g.vs["age"] = [25, 31, 18, 47, 22, 23, 50]   
In [5]: g.vs["gender"] = ["f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "m"]   
In [6]: g.es["is_formal"] = [False, False, True, True, True, False, True, False, False]  
In [7]: atr = 'age'    
In [8]: c = 30    
In [9]: list(g.vs(**{'{}_lt'.format(atr): c}))
Out[9]: 
[igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x7f06ae24f810>,0,{'gender': 'f', 'age': 25, 'name': 'Alice'}),
 igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x7f06ae24f810>,2,{'gender': 'f', 'age': 18, 'name': 'Claire'}),
 igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x7f06ae24f810>,4,{'gender': 'f', 'age': 22, 'name': 'Esther'}),
 igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x7f06ae24f810>,5,{'gender': 'm', 'age': 23, 'name': 'Frank'})]

In [10]: list(v for v in g.vs if v[atr] < c)
Out[10]: 
[igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x7f06ae24f810>,0,{'gender': 'f', 'age': 25, 'name': 'Alice'}),
 igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x7f06ae24f810>,2,{'gender': 'f', 'age': 18, 'name': 'Claire'}),
 igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x7f06ae24f810>,4,{'gender': 'f', 'age': 22, 'name': 'Esther'}),
 igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x7f06ae24f810>,5,{'gender': 'm', 'age': 23, 'name': 'Frank'})]
```

You won't all len etc.. on the gen exp  but it seems pretty efficient if you just want the filtered elements:

```
In [14]: timeit list(v for v in g.vs if v[atr] < c)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.7 µs per loop

In [15]: timeit list(g.vs(**{'{}_lt'.format(atr): c}))
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.5 µs per loop
```

Comment: Both answers were helpful but I will mark this as the answer for both mentioning about the speed aspect and being the first answer.

Answer (score 3):

[When the first parameter to select is a callable](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.VertexSeq-class.html#select), the vertex is selected if the callable returns `True`.

In this way, you can apply relatively more complex queries. For example:

```
import igraph

G = igraph.Graph() 
G.add_vertex("John", age=22) 
G.add_vertex("Vilma", age=20) 
G.add_edge("John", "Vilma") 
vRes = G.vs.select(lambda x:x["name"]=="John" and x["age"]>20)
#Or, with query parameters as below
#someAttribute = "age"
#someValue = 20
#vRes = G.vs.select(lambda x:x[someAttribute] > someValue)
```

Within the `lambda` above, argument x is an [igraph::Vertex](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Vertex-class.html) which provides access to all vertex attributes.

[A similar interface](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.EdgeSeq-class.html#select) exists to select edges.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about this syntax either. I am curious whether `(v for v in g.vs if v[atr] < c)` and `G.vs.select(lambda x:x["name"]=="John" and x["age"]>20)` has any performance difference...

Comment: I got curious too after this. All that `select` does is `filtered_idxs=[i for i, v in enumerate(values) if func(v, value)]` which is a list comprehension but the generator expression suggested above will return an iterator which is more efficient, especially if the filtered nodes are to be traversed just once. (http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/ ).

Comment: I was actually just checking the [same thing](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph-pysrc.html#VertexSeq.select). :-)